# SAS on Windows7: do not use recycle bin

Tags: windows, sas, recycle-bin

Problem: I am creating big temporary files while performing some simulations ~650-1200MB. So I wish to delete them as my hard drive has only a few GB space left. However SAS places the deleted files automatically in the "Windows recycle bin", which fills up my hard drive.

Question: It there a SAS-option to bypass the recycle bin on Windows systems?

SOLUTION (Edit2): clearly a user error (mine). Question can be closed.

No info here: 
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/64892/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1tmgku1vq7pwqn1iqioeflxgec1.htm

Nor there: 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/64892/PDF/default/lesysoptsref.pdf

EDIT: 
I used now PROC SQL and DROP TABLE 
and PROC DATASETS and DELETE 
but strangely the table does not show up in the recycle bin... 
I will investigate that further.

Comment: you can be nice without "hi out there" and "thanks in advance". Both phrases are not very welcome at stack overflow. With which SAS command do you try to delete the file ? You should edit your question and add this information.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me.  How do the files end up in the recycle bin?  How are you deleting them?  You need more information than this to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `x` statements (see EXAMPLE 1 in the link) 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/036-31.pdf
(Though proc datasets/delete should permanently delete them - odd it doesn't work for you)

An example of deleting a file from your work folder using the `x` statement:

```
data delete_me;
  x = 1;
run;

x ' del "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\delete_me.txt" ';
```

Comment: Hi Elena,welcome to Stack Overflow!  Rather than just linking to whitepapers it is preferred that answers paraphrase the relevant pieces of information.  This is to ensure your answer will remain useful to others even if the link breaks.  I will edit your question to include the relevant piece of information as I'm not sure that you have enough reputation to do that just yet.